# How do I override an 'onkeyup' event trigger to allow navigating table rows with arrow keys?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have created a simple search field that will ajax in relevant search results as a user types into an input field. Everything works great, except for one thing. The input field has an `onkeyup` event that triggers a jQuery function that grabs the search results, which are displayed to the user in a table. The first result (row) is highlighted. I want to allow the user to use the arrow keys to navigate up and down the table of search results. However, since the input field has the `onkeyup` event trigger, as soon as I press the down arrow key (briefly highlighting the next table row) my `onkeyup` jQuery function is triggered again, re-highlighting the first search result (first row). I need a way to prevent the `onkeyup` function from triggering every time arrow keys are "un-pressed." Does this make sense? Am I approaching this the wrong way? Here is some of the code:

HTML:

```
<input id="search" type="text" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" />
```

jQuery:

```
function showResult(str)
{
    var e = str.charAt( str.length-1 )

    if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40)
    {
        $(document).keydown(function(e)
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 40)
            { 
               $('tr.highlight').next("tr").addClass("highlight");
               $('tr.highlight:first').removeClass("highlight");
               return false;
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 38)
            { 
               $('tr.highlight').prev("tr").addClass("highlight");
               $('tr.highlight:last').removeClass("highlight");
               return false;
            }
        });
    else
    {
        // code that gets the search results
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but a much simpler solution would be:

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EwB6s/1/

JavaScript

```
$(function(){    
    $('#search').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40){
            if (e.keyCode == 40){ 
               alert('down'); 
               return false;
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 38){ 
               alert('up'); 
               return false;
            }
        }else{
            // code that gets the search results
            alert('ajax'); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

​

HTML

```
<input id='search' type='text' />​
```

Comment: I tried it on jsfiddle and it works fine, but when I copied the exact same code and tried to use it on my site it didn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I put it in <script> tags in the <head></head> and made sure the exact same plain <input type='text' /> tag was in the body. ???

Comment: @JohnAnderson - You may have forgotten to add the code to the jQuery ready event. If you simply place the script inside the script tag at the top of the page then it will execute before the input tags below it have rendered. Also, my example was adding this event to every input on the page. Using jQuery's selectors you can select by ID using the syntax `$('#IdOfControl')`. I modified my examples above to address both concerns. Let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: Thanks so much! You helped me figure out the issues I was having.